# How to remove loose seat post stuck down inside tube, without saddle to grip?

Tags: seatpost

I was reading this forum the other day to see how I could get the seat post out of the frame.  I was putting a new bike together and had never done so before. I messed up and let the post go into the tube Thursday evening.

I tried needle-nose pliers, the only thing I could get on the post, but it wouldn't budge.  I tried a wire and couldn't hook it.  Yesterday I put a lubricant into the tube, but still couldn't budge the post.  Today I sprayed white lithium into the tube and eventually I hooked the post with a wire.  However, I couldn't hold the wire because I had some lubricant on my hands. I got a pair of pliers to use to tug on the wire.  BINGO the post slid right out. I couldn't believe it. So I thought I would pass along my dilemma and how I solved it. I actually never thought the post would come out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question

Comment: @Swifty - The question is legit if it's posed as a question and then answered.

Comment: “Last resort”: You could have also removed the crankset and bottom bracket to get access to the other end of the seat tube.

Comment: @DanielRHicks you might be right, but it isn't either of those things

Comment: @jean Welcome to the site - great work solving your problem, but right now its not a great fit for the Q&A format.  Try pasting your solution as an answer, below.  Noone can do this for you - you have to do it.